Why @ExampleObject doesn't work in Swagger
I'm trying to add some examples to the swagger documentation. I want to do this using the @ExampleObject annotation.
Here is my test controller.
@Operation(summary = "Create new Employee", responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {
                @Content(
                    mediaType = "application/json",
                    array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = EmployeeCreateRequestDto.class)),
                    examples = {
                        @ExampleObject(name = "Example 1", summary = "Summary 1", description = "Some desc", 
                            value = "[{\"firstName\":\"Ram\",\"lastName\":\"Gurram\"},{\"firstName\":\"Krishna\",\"lastName\":\"N\"}]")
                    }
                )
            })
        })
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeCreateRequestDto>> createEmployee(
        @RequestBody(description = "Create new user", required = true, 
        content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
            array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = EmployeeCreateRequestDto.class)),
            examples = {
                    @ExampleObject(name = "Example 1", summary = "Summary 1", description = "sample payload", 
                        value = "[{\"firstName\":\"Ram\",\"lastName\":\"Gurram\"},{\"firstName\":\"Krishna\",\"lastName\":\"N\"}]")
                }))
        @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody List<EmployeeCreateRequestDto> dtos) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(dtos, HttpStatus.CREATED);

}

private static class EmployeeCreateRequestDto {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}

I tried updating dependency versions, tried using @ExamleObjects in the @Parametrs annotation - nothing helps.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
